# While loop stuck on first query result

Tags: php

I'm relatively new to php and am in the process of transferring a search engine i wrote to OOP.

Relevant SQL connection code/sqlconnect1 class:

```
    public function query($query){
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){     
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }

        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }
    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

While loop:

```
$search = new LoadSearch;
$sqlconnect1 = new sqlconnect1;
$sqlconnect1->query("SELECT * FROM data1 WHERE address_city LIKE 'austin' AND address_zip LIKE '78758'");

    //Assign Variables and Display Record Results
    while ($row1 = $sqlconnect1->resultset()){
    $Name1=$row1['name'];
    $Address1=$row1['address_1'];
    $City1=$row1['address_city'];
    $State1=$row1['address_state'];
    $ZIP1=$row1['address_zip'];
    $Country1=$row1['address_country'];
    $Phone1=$row1['phone'];
    $Website1=$row1['website'];
    $Category_11=$row1['category_1'];
    $Category_21=$row1['category_2'];
    echo"

    <!--Table 2-->  

    <table class='table2'>

        <tr>
            <td></td><td><b>$Name1</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td><td>$Address1, $City1, $State1 $ZIP1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td><td>$Country1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td><td>$Phone1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td><td>$Category_11</td>
        </tr>

    </table>";
```

Whenever the page is loaded, it repeats the first query result indefinitely and never moves beyond the first result. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. A similar setup worked fine when it was procedural.

Comment: what the hell is `sqlconnect1` class ? :)

Comment: @Diego Mariani   Like I said, I'm new. I think people usually name it database. The first segment of code is from the sqlconnect1 class which has all the database connection information.

Comment: @sectus   I tried fetchAll, but It just seems to return everything in the database. I'm only assuming that, because the tables load, but they never fill up with data. It just repeats the table indefinitely down the page with nothing in it.

Comment: Remove execute from that function. Call execute before loop.

Comment: remove the execute into result set, because every time you fetch, you also execute and you're going to get always the same result (the 1st)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `$this->execute()` call, that's because you call on every loop iteration [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and then [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). In such way you're going to retrieve always the same result (the first row)

```
public function resultset(){
    // $this->execute(); -- Remove this line
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Obviously you need to call `$sqlconnect1->execute()` before your while loop