# PHP while loop loops everything except first query result

Tags: php, sql, pdo, while-loop, prepared-statement

I am struggling to understand why while loop not looping through the first query result.

```
$pdo = new PDO('connection');
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user FROM records
ORDER BY date DESC");

$stmt2->execute();
$r2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($r2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<tr><td>' . $r1['user'] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957127/while-loop-stuck-on-first-query-result) thread but it is OOP. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ahh don't fetch data twice!! and confuse with  `$stmt2` and `$stmt1`

Comment: first, check the return value of `->execute()`. if it's `===FALSE` the query failed and you should check the `$stmt->errorInfo()`. Also as Saty said, don't fetch twice. only fetch in the loop. If there's no output, the query failed or the database table is empty (or only has one entry which you discard by your first fetch). I even overlooked the `$stmt1` and `$stmt2` confusion. Damn. Saty, take my upvote.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now but I was using `$r1`for not while loop, e.g. `echo $r1['user']`. I would like to use something like this: `while ($r1 = $r1)` but it crashes my page. It is possible to use variable `$r1` somehow in the while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're fetching it twice. Remove the `fetch` just before while loop.

To something like this,

```
$pdo = new PDO('connection');
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user FROM records
ORDER BY date DESC");

$stmt2->execute();
while ($r1 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<tr><td>' . $r1['user'] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You already have fetched the first record by `$r1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, and fetching the rest in `while` loop. This should work -

```
$stmt2->execute();

while ($r1 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<tr><td>' . $r1['user'] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just wondering if it is possible to use fetch variable in the while loop? Like the following: `while ($row = $r1) { echo $row['user']; }`?

Comment: Currently it is doing the same. Why do you need to do that way?

Comment: Because if I removed the first one `$r2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, then other queries won't be successful, for instance this: `echo 'Player ' . $r2['user'];`, which is not in the while loop. How can I do that?

Comment: You are running a single query. It should print all the rows.

Comment: It prints only in the while loop, that is the problem.

Comment: Then you can get the first value and manually print it outside the loop and after that the while loop will do.

Comment: Could you give an example, please?